# Javascript if else statement. Variables in HTML stored in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make an event when two numbers randomly generated are equal.So I need to store values in a variable in javascript and see if they are equal.

```
if (target_number == you_score){
console.log(1)
}
```

I have put console.log in there to test if the statement is executed

```
const button = document.querySelector('target_number')

function getRandomNumber() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)
}
function getRandomNumber2() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)
}
function getRandomNumber3() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)
}

document.getElementById("target_number").addEventListener("click", displayGuess);
function displayGuess(){
  document.getElementById("target_number").innerHTML = getRandomNumber();
}
document.getElementById("target_number").style.cursor = "pointer";

document.getElementById("computer_score").addEventListener("click", displayGuess2);
function displayGuess2(){
  document.getElementById("computer_score").innerHTML = getRandomNumber2()
}
document.getElementById("computer_score").style.cursor = "pointer";

document.getElementById("you_score").addEventListener("click", displayGuess3);
function displayGuess3(){
  document.getElementById("you_score").innerHTML = getRandomNumber3()
}
document.getElementById("you_score").style.cursor = "pointer";


var computerScore = document.getElementById("computer_score") 
var youScore = document.getElementById("you_score")
var targetNumber = document.getElementById("target_number")
```

Here is my HTML. I would like to make a if else statement in script that checks if the value of target_number and computer_score are equal

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Number Guesser</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div>
  <h1>Number Guesser</h1>
</div>
<div>
  <h2>Round 
    <span class="round_number">1</span>
  </h2>
</div>
<h3>Target Number: <span id="target_number">Blank</span></h3>
</body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="computer">Computer
    <div>Score <span id="computer_score">0</span></div>
  </div>
  <div class="you">You
    <div>Score <span id="you_score">0</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
<h1 id="new">New</h1>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what to refer to as elements, attributes or variables. My head is toasty XD

Answer (score 0):

Based on what it looks like you mean, I have simplified your code using [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation), some css and a single function to generate a random number lower than 10.

```js
const someNumberLT10 = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);

document.addEventListener(`click`, handle);

function handle(evt) {
  if (evt.target.id === "play") {
    //               ^ button#play was clicked
    const youNr = someNumberLT10();
    const computerNr = someNumberLT10();
    // two random numbers < 10 are generated and stored into variables

    document.querySelector(`#you_score`).textContent = youNr;
    document.querySelector(`#computer_score`).textContent = computerNr;
    // ^ numbers are displayed

    document.querySelector(`#equal`).textContent = `Equal? ${
      youNr === computerNr ? `Yes! ` : `Nope ... `}`;
    // ^ score (equal or not) is displayed

    const round = document.querySelector(`[data-round]`);
    round.dataset.round = +round.dataset.round + 1;
    // ^ round index is set
  }
}
```

```css
[data-round]:after {
  content:' 'attr(data-round);
}
```

```html
<h2 data-round="1">Round</h2>
<!-- data-round is a so called data attribute. It can be used as a variable
     in js (dataset). Here, js is used to set the value, and css is used 
     to display the value ([data-round]:after) -->
<h3>Target Number: <button id="play">Create</button></h3>
<div class="container">
  <div>Computer score <span id="computer_score">0</span></div>
  <div>Your score <span id="you_score">0</span></div>
  <div id="equal"></div>
</div>
```